# Magento 2: Backend Related, Upp-Sell and Cross-Sell Product Tab Filter Issue

Tags: magento2, product, filter, related-products

When I filter Product By Name in related product tab product filter Working Completed, but without product add called save function directly and page redirect to the Catalogue page.Any idea,please Help me.